# Boot stuck after update Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, kubuntu, plymouth

So I have been distro hopping a bit lately and one thing that has been happening is that after an update my machine just won't boot. At first I had KDE Neon when this happened. At first I thought it was a fluke and decided to just install Kubuntu since I was interested in trying it. When I updated it happened again. When I boot my machine just gets stuck on the Republic of Gamers logo. I decided to go into my BIOS and select the ubuntu disk in the boot menu. This time I was stuck on a message that says `[OK] Finished terminate Plymouth boot screen`. I am able to press alt + F2 to go into tty3 and I tried running firefox to see what would happen (I have no idea what I am doing at this point). When i enter `sudo firefox` in the command line and press enter I get two lines that say:

`mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified`

Here are my computer specs:

CPU: Intel core i7 4400K

Graphics: Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB

RAM: 6GB

I used the Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ISO for installation.

I really don't want to run Windows so any help is greatly appreciated lol

Comment: Hi! The ISO I used for installation I downloaded from the Kubuntu website and it is the Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ISO. Other than the system updates there were no other changes.

Comment: fyi:  don't run `sudo firefox` as it's a user-level intended app; and is not intended to be run with elevated privileges... the errors you mention on `sudo firefox` ARE CORRECT as that's a result of user-error in execution (user behavior being the issue)

Comment: With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. I learned a few things along the way. First what I did was boot into recovery mode. Right before the Plymouth boot splash screen press Esc key. On the next menu I chose Advanced Options for Ubuntu. Then I chose a recovery mode kernel. After that my pc booted up to the desktop. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Turns out that the Nvidia driver updates were being held up for some reason and was not able to update them using `sudo apt upgrade` instead I ran `sudo aptitude full-upgrade` and the drivers installed. After a reboot my computer boots just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for ubutnu22.04, and I solved that by changing the graphics driver from "software and Updates". It used to be the last option (xserver) and I changed that to the first one (check the image below).
[image]

BTW, I was not able to go to ubuntu screen directly, so I had to go to an older version through GRUB (hold shift while you see the PC logo, and then go to advanced options for Ubutntu, then choose an older version)